# How long are certificates available in ADCS Web Enrollment page after issued

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate-authority, active-directory-adcs

I have a windows 2008 enterprise ADCS server with web enrollment. I want to know/configure how long do **issued** certificates last on the page before a user has to submit another request.

While researching this question, this seams to be different from certdat.inc's "nPendingTimoutDays" since this controls pending requests, not already issued certificates.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/change-certificates-expiration-date

Comment: @joeqwerty your link is about how to change the cert's validity date, which is not what I'm asking. To be more clear, what I'm asking is: once issued, how long do these certificates stay posted on the user's web ernollment page?